# How to create a COUNTIF to find text that's in a cell in a column containing long strings

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I am trying to find how to search for specific key words in a string of answers from a survey. For example, trying to find the word excited in a list of 100 survey string answers.

I currently am using the following formula

```
=COUNTIF(G3:G24,""*"&C4&"*"")
```

However the issue I'm having is that the double quotation marks are recognized as a zero but I'm looking to perform a countif on `"*excited*"` but trying to use the cell to dictate what word will searched for. The way i have it currently written it is performing a COUNTIF on `""*excited*""`

How do I get rid of the double quotes on either side and keep it as only a single set so that it can properly search?

Comment: So after that edit: `=COUNTIF(G3:G24,"*"&C4&"*")` maybe?

Comment: I was able to count the cells by using `=Countifs( [cells], "*"&[Excited]&"*")`. Alternatively, you can add a column next to your data using a `Find` function to get a number value and countifs that column contains a number.